# Elasticsearch, date histogram omits buckets

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query, date-histogram

I am trying to get a result like the kibana "discover" tab like below

[image]

via **date_histogram** functionality

my request is as below

```
GET index-*/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "stats": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "min_doc_count": 0,
        "missing": 0, 
        "time_zone": "+03:00",
        "field": "@timestamp",
        "fixed_interval": "1h",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
      }
    }
  },
    "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "@timestamp": {
              "format": "strict_date_optional_time",
              "gte": "2022-08-01T11:00:00.000Z",
              "lte": "2022-08-02T11:14:34.158Z"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

resulting in correct query verifying from the number of total hits

```
{
  "took": 4,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 6,
    "successful": 6,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 782,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "stats": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key_as_string": "2022-08-01 14:00:00",
          "key": 1659351600000,
          "doc_count": 450
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "2022-08-01 15:00:00",
          "key": 1659355200000,
          "doc_count": 265
        },
...................................
        {
          "key_as_string": "2022-08-02 09:00:00",
          "key": 1659420000000,
          "doc_count": 0
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "2022-08-02 10:00:00",
          "key": 1659423600000,
          "doc_count": 31
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "2022-08-02 11:00:00",
          "key": 1659427200000,
          "doc_count": 0
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "2022-08-02 12:00:00",
          "key": 1659430800000,
          "doc_count": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**the problem is that it does not return empty buckets that are in the end even if `min_doc_count` is  set to 0. The number of buckets is 23 not 24 and only the last non-empty bucket is returned**

If the last bucket is not empty then 24 are shown correctly. The in-between empty buckets are shown correctly to 0.

how can I fix my missing buckets ? Maybe its not possible with date_histogram ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try [`extended_bounds`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-histogram-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-histogram-aggregation-extended-bounds) with the same date range as in your range filter in order to include the first or last buckets, even if they are empty:

```
GET index-*/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "stats": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "min_doc_count": 0,
        "missing": 0, 
        "time_zone": "+03:00",
        "field": "@timestamp",
        "fixed_interval": "1h",
        "extended_bounds": {
          "min": "2022-08-01T11:00:00.000Z",
          "max": "2022-08-02T11:14:34.158Z"
        }
      }
    }
  },
    "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "@timestamp": {
              "format": "strict_date_optional_time",
              "gte": "2022-08-01T11:00:00.000Z",
              "lte": "2022-08-02T11:14:34.158Z"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes thats it, works correctly, thank you very much! Just a small modification, "format" needs to be removed as it does not coincide with the default format. Can you edit your answer so the next person that may need this does not get confused ? In any case this selected answer is final for me.

Comment: now i have to put it all in spring boot :)

Answer (score 2):

**Explanation of the behavior mentioned in the question**

Histogram buckets are created based on the dates returned in the documents being aggregated. So first bucket is based on the earliest date in documents returned and last bucket on the latest date. Then buckets in between are created(missing are assigned 0 value).

As @Val mentioned you can use **extended_bounds** setting, which enables extending the bounds of the histogram beyond the data itself.